# Why would I be unable to convert an instance of a class to an instance of the class's subclass in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using a library that has a function that returns an instance of some class `Engine`.

I'd like to tack on some interfaces to `Engine`, so I subclass it `class InterfacedEngine extends Engine implements AwesomeInterface`.

But when I change the code that uses the classes from this:

```
var engine:Engine = generateEngine();
```

to this:

```
var interfacedEngine:InterfacedEngine = generateEngine();
```

It gives me a runtime error (elision mine):

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert ...::Engine@1bc2bf11 to ....InterfacedEngine.
```

What about AS3 classes am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B is the base class and D extends B then a D is a B, but not the opposite. That means a reference of type B can refer to both B and D. But a reference of type D can only refer to D, not B. `InterfacedEngine` can only refer `InterfacedEngine`, not it's base `Engine`. But a `Engine` type can refer to both `Engine` and `InterfacedEngine`.

```
var eng1:Engine = new Engine(); // valid
var eng2:Engine = new InterfacedEngine(); // valid
var eng3:InterfacedEngine = new InterfacedEngine(); // valid
var eng4:InterfacedEngine = new Engine(); // not valid
```

Comment: That makes sense. Can you recommend a solution given this insight? I'd like to add functionality to a class. I don't have any major moral objections to creating a class with my new functionality that simply wraps around `Engine` as a private variable, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: If `generateEngine()` return a `InterfacedEngine` then you have no problem. If `generateEngine()` creates a `Engine` then you are not getting any new functionality. To get new functionality added by `InterfacedEngine` you need to create a real `InterfacedEngine`. Check that whether you can change `generateEngine()` to create `InterfacedEngine`. And object composition as your comment is also another way to add functionality like inheritance. You can do that too if that is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this kind of problem is the Proxy design pattern.
You can read up on it here: http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html

Basically you create a placeholder for another class. This is done through composition instead of inheritance though.

[image: diagram]

InterfaceEngine should accept an object of type Engine as a constructor parameter. AwesomeINterface defines all the Engine methods you need.
InterfaceEngine just passes the method call to the corresponding meths of the Engine object it's holding onto.

Comment: Yes, this is basically exactly what I did originally. And I thought that was a messy way to do things, hence this exploration. I think I'll go with this proxy pattern then. It's a shame that AS3 doesn't have an equivalent of Ruby's `#method_missing` function to make the proxy easier to use, but I'll deal. If you have any recommendations on that front, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well, obviously there's the native Proxy class, which allows (if I'm not mistaken) for exactly the same kind of functionality as Ruby's method_missing, but I don't think it can be of any help since the whole idea is to have an interface, which means the methods need to be implemented anyway.